# Upgrade ServiceMix 3.0 to ServiceMix 6.0 with Camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I have create one small java based application using ***ServiceMix 3.0 with JBI messaging.***

Application work as, we are reading one file location using filepoller(every 5mins) and transfer the files into the other format ie. xml to pdf.

Output file we write on some other file location using servixmix filewriter component.

Now we need to upgrade with **Apache ServiceMix 6.0 and Camel 2.15.2**.

I'm new for Apache Camel. I had done some POC work on servicemix 6.0 and camel 2.15.2 but not getting whole idea, for achieve our application scenario?.

POC work like using file, timer, Scheduler camel component.

```
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("timer://foo?period=1000").process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Hello world  :"
                            + new java.util.Date().toString());
                }
            });
        }

    });
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.stop();
```

Can anyone help for achieve above scenario.

Please all suggest some other way to get the scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For read files you can use `file` (http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) component. For write files you can use `file` component too.
I don't know anything about the format of your files, therefore can't advise anything about their processing.

For processing you can use such components as:

`xslt` (transform XML http://camel.apache.org/xslt.html),

`fop` (transform to PDF http://camel.apache.org/fop.html),

`velocity` (transform to XML by template http://camel.apache.org/velocity.html), etc.

or you can use some data formats : http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html like **BeanIO** (http://camel.apache.org/beanio.html).

Example:

```
    from("file://inbox?sortBy=file:name&include=(.*[.](xml|XML)$)&delete=true&preMove=inprogress&delay=300000"). 
     //5 min. delay between poll, consuming only xml file
      routeId("testRoute")
    .to("xslt:xsl/transform.xsl") //refers to the file xsl/transform.xsl on the classpath
     //....... some other transformation here .......
    .to("file://outbox");
```